# CentOS7 で firewalld を直接実行するとサービスに登録されずプロセスだけ起動するのはなぜ？

Tags: linux, centos

CentOS7 で firewalldコマンドを直接実行するとサービスに登録されずプロセスだけ起動するのはなぜ？
firewalldを使用せず、別のファイアウォールでアクセス制限をしています。

```
$firewalld
```

を実行しました。
エラーなどはなくコマンドが実行された反応でした。

```
$systemctl status firewalld
```

を実行すると

```
Active: inactive (dead)
```

しかし、ファイアウォールは起動していて外から80番ポートを通してApacheにアクセスできない状態でした。

```
$ps -aux | grep firewalld
```

を実行しました。

```
root     30074  0.0  0.1 363100 31900 ?        Ssl  18:14   0:02 /usr/bin/python2 -Es /sbin/firewalld
```

このプロセス番号をkillすることで、firewallは切れて再び80番ポートでアクセスできました。

systemctl statusでサービスの確認ではfairewalldが止まっていたので、なぜアクセスできないのか調査に時間を要してしまいました。

なぜプロセスだけ起動できるようになっているのでしょうか？

firewalldを使わないでアクセス制限をしている場合
このような状態にならないためには

```
enable -n firewalld
```

が適切でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firewalld に限らず、いわゆるデーモンとして動作するプログラムは本来、個別のコマンドで起動や停止を行うことができます。しかし、プログラムごとに操作方法は異なるため、Systemd 経由にすることで統一された操作を行う事が出来ます。

サービスへの登録はあくまで Systemd が担っているので、直接起動されたプロセスについては勝手にサービスには登録されませんし、起動状態の関知も出来ません。

firewalld は Systemd 用の定義ファイル (=ユニットファイル) が予め用意されているので、基本的には `systemctl` コマンド経由で有効・無効の切り替えや起動・停止の管理を行うことを推奨します。

[Enable and Disable firewalld](https://firewalld.org/documentation/howto/enable-and-disable-firewalld.html)

> firewalld provides an init script for systems using classic SysVinit and also a systemd service file.
>
> ```
> systemctl unmask --now firewalld.service
> systemctl enable --now firewalld.service
> ```

**参考:**
[systemdとは](https://www.designet.co.jp/faq/term/?id=c3lzdGVtZA)